# Magento Doesn't Run SQL Install/Update Script

Tags: magento

I have problem with configuration or something else that magento never run my module's sql install/update script!

I use magento-1.4.1.0

Here is my structure folders and files:

```
\app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl
\app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\Block\ShortUrl.php

\app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\controllers\IndexController.php
\app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\controllers\UController.php

\app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\etc\config.xml

\app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\Helper\Url.php

\app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\Model\ShortUrl.php
\app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\Model\Mysql4\ShortUrl.php
\app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\Model\Mysql4\ShortUrl\Collection.php

\app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\Model
\app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\Model\Mysql4
\app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\Model\Mysql4\ShortUrl

\app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\sql\rn_shorturl_setup\mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
```

Here are the contents of `\app\etc\modules\RN_ShortUrl.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<config>
    <modules>
        <RN_ShortUrl>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </RN_ShortUrl>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Here are the contents of `\app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\etc\config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <RN_ShortUrl>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </RN_ShortUrl>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <shorturl>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>RN_ShortUrl</module>
                <frontName>shorturl</frontName>
            </args>
        </shorturl>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <shorturl>
                <file>shorturl.xml</file>
            </shorturl>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <rn_shorturl>
            <class>RN_ShortUrl_Block</class>
        </rn_shorturl>
    </blocks>
    <rewrite>
        <rn_shorturl>
            <from>#^/u/(.*)#</from>
            <to>/shorturl/u/redirect/key/$1</to>
        </rn_shorturl>
    </rewrite>

    <models>
        <shorturl>
            <class>RN_ShortUrl_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>shorturl_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </shorturl>
        <shorturl_mysql4>
            <class>RN_ShortUrl_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <shorturl>
                    <table>shorturl</table>
                </shorturl>
            </entities>
        </shorturl_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <shorturl_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>RN_ShortUrl</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </shorturl_setup>
        <shorturl_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </shorturl_write>
        <shorturl_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </shorturl_read>
    </resources>
    <helpers>
        <shorturl>
            <class>RN_ShortUrl_Helper</class>
        </shorturl>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

Here is my install SQL script:

```
<?php
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();

    $installer->run("
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('shorturl')};
            CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('shorturl')} (
            `shorturl_id` INTEGER(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `shorted_key` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            `long_url` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            PRIMARY KEY (`shorturl_id`),
            INDEX (shorted_key),
            INDEX (long_url)
            )ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';"
    );

    /* right before this */
    $installer->endSetup();
```

I have tried to change my module's version and created the upgrade script "mysql4-upgrade-1.0-1.1.php" but still not working, but I could run my module.

http://magento.test/shorturl/index/generate/?url=http://realestate.cambodiachic.com/property-detail-hotel-restaurant-on-kampot-river-93.html

It's working except the problem I am asking.

Thanks in advance,

Rithy

Comment: Tip: if you want to get questions answered, do **not** put words like "Urgent" in the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, Now I can solve this problem!

1. In my model, I've tried to create a function to delete the record in the core_resources table which we could use/call from our helper.

\app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\Model\ShortUrl.php

```
    public function removeShortedUrlModule()
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM `core_resource`
        WHERE `code`='shorturl_setup';";
        $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');     
        try {
            $connection->query($sql);
            die('deleted module in core_resource!');
        } catch (Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

2 . Change folder name \app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\sql\ **rn_shorturl_setup**\

To \app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\sql\ **shorturl_setup**\

Finally I soved it! CHEER!

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that when you changed your version number you created an upgrade for 1.0-1.1, but your version is actually 0.1.0. That may explain why it didn't "upgrade". You may want to delete the row entirely from core resource and let it "reinstall" itself on the next page load.

Or, amend your script so that it is tagged as an upgrade from 0.1.0-0.1.1.

Comment: how to delete the row entirely from the core resource?
My database is in vm ware and currently I don't know how to access to see the database...

Comment: If you don't have database access, fixing your upgrade script to use the correct versions will be the easiest route.

Comment: Could you provide me some concept of naming the upgrade script file?
currently my module's version in 0.2.1 and I created a file name mysql4-upgrade-0.2.0-0.2.1.php but it's still not run.

Comment: You need to make sure that you have the *current* version correct as well. If you previously had moved from 0.1.0 to 0.1.1 the current version is probably 0.1.1, in which case your script should be called mysql4-upgrade-0.1.1-0.2.1.php. If you have the wrong version for either the new or the old one, the script won't run.

Comment: OK, thanks I got it, I'm checking what is my current version in database by creating backup database in backend and check. Then what I shoud do is to set in the module's version is the next version I want, and the script file should be name "mysql4-upgrade-[current_version in database]-[next_version in the config].php" right?

Comment: OK, I've tried many times, but it's still not run the script :(
Anyways thanks ur help!

Comment: Okay, then you should find the credentials for the database and delete the row from the core_resources table. At next page load, Magento will reinstall the plugin from scratch.

Comment: OK, Now I can solve this problem!

1. In my model, I've tried to create a function to delete the record in the core_resources table.
2. Change folder \app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\sql\rn_shorturl_setup
To \app\code\local\RN\ShortUrl\sql\shorturl_setup

Finally I soved it! CHEER!